# what are the coset of $N$ if $G$ is equal to $D_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G=D_8$, and let $N=\{e,a^2,a^4,a^6\}$.

(a) Find all left cosets and all right cosets of $N$, and verify that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
(b) Show that $G/N$ has order $4$, but is not cyclic.

Comment: What have you tried? We can help you better when we know exactly where you're struggling. Moreover, your question will be better received if it doesn't look like you want us to do your homework for you.

Comment: On a more pragmatic note, what is $a$ in this situation? I assume it's the group element corresponding to "rotation by 90 degrees", but it's not clear from the question. Also, is $D_8$ the dihedral group with $8$ elements? or the dihedral group of an $8$-gon?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I would say from the context that $a$ is rotation by 45 degrees, and $D8$ stands for dihedral group of order 16.